# Executable jar file not running after building in netbeans

Tags: java, jar, build, executable-jar, netbeans-8

I tried to clean and build our program in netbeans 8.2 to see if it can build an executable jar and it did. The problem is whenever I double click the jar file, nothing would happen. I tried building a different program and the jar file for that ran properly. What should I do to make it run? Here's the output when I tried to build the program:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\PAULO\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SAD -
Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: 
C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build
Updating property file: 
C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\generated-
sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 6 source files to 
C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\src\sad\BEO.java uses or 
overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Copying 36 files to 
C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\dist\SAD.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\dist\SAD.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Comment: *"To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\PAULO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SAD\dist\SAD.jar"* - have you tried executing it from the command line?

Comment: Yeah I tried but it's showing me this error: Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'

has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required. Error: could not find java.dll Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: Ok, now I tried changing the current version to 1.7 in regedit and now it shows me an error: unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Uninstall Java (jdk and jre) and reinstall the jdk

Comment: I just saw that I have 2 versions of java. Should I uninstall both?

Comment: Ok, now I tried deleting jdk 8 and did not do anything to the jdk 7. Whenever I try to run it in the command line, there would be no errors but nothing also happens.

Comment: Without the code, it's impossible to suggest more

Comment: Yeah, I can't paste the code here since it's really long and it runs properly on NetBeans. It's just that it won't run on the jar file. Thanks for helping me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The main culprits were having two different jdk and the main class that's being used is incorrect. I just uninstalled one jdk and changed my main class to the right one.